How to pass limit or size as query parameter so that JPA retrieves all results
How to pass limit or size as query parameter so that JPA retrieves all Students, instead of in a paginated form. (i.e. limit = all students), but how do I do this in a generic way and how should the query parameter should look like which is JPA compliant for this method
public List<Student> searchStudents(Pageable pageable) {
}


Use Pageable.unpaged():

Returns a Pageable instance representing no pagination setup.

Usage:
List<Student> allStudents = something.searchStudents(Pageable.unpaged());


no I want the query parameter to be intelligent enough so that the injected Pageable does an unpaged request to the repository

@user352290 Edit question to include the current handler method definition. Also add on which parameter values you want to do unpaged request. What you want is not possible out of the box AFAIK, so you will need some manual work.
